# Getting error after update identity column names

Tags: c#, abp

I'm working on ABP framework version 7.1, with Angular UI

I renamed and set to required two identityUser columns in my dbcontext as:

```
builder.Entity<IdentityUser>(b =>
        {
            b.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasColumnName("FirstName");
            b.Property(x => x.Surname).IsRequired().HasColumnName("LastName");
        });
```

I created the migration and updated the database. It works correctly, now my database has that column names.

But when I run the data seeder, I get an error:

> Cannot insert null into column name LastName, table AbpUsers, the
> column does not allow nulls.

So I try to create my Identity seeder as:

```
 [Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
public class CustomIdentityDataSeederContributor : IdentityDataSeeder
{

    public CustomIdentityDataSeederContributor(
        IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager,
        IGuidGenerator guidGenerator,
        IIdentityRoleRepository roleRepository,
        IIdentityUserRepository userRepository,
        ILookupNormalizer lookupNormalizer,
        IdentityUserManager userManager,
        IdentityRoleManager roleManager,
        ICurrentTenant currentTenant,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> identityOptions,
        IdentityUserManager identityUserManager)
        : base(guidGenerator, roleRepository, userRepository, lookupNormalizer, userManager, roleManager, currentTenant, identityOptions)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<IdentityDataSeedResult> SeedAsync(string adminEmail, string adminPassword, Guid? tenantId = null)
    {
        var result = new IdentityDataSeedResult();
        Check.NotNullOrWhiteSpace(adminEmail, nameof(adminEmail));
        Check.NotNullOrWhiteSpace(adminPassword, nameof(adminPassword));
        string adminUserName = "custom";
        if (adminEmail == "admin@abp.io")
        {
            return result;
        }
        if (tenantId != Guid.Empty && tenantId != null)
        {
            adminUserName = "custom2";
            if (adminEmail == "custom@Custom.com")
            {
                adminEmail = "custom2@Custom.com";
            }
        }

        using (CurrentTenant.Change(tenantId))
        {
            //"admin" user

            var adminUser = await UserRepository.FindByNormalizedUserNameAsync(
                LookupNormalizer.NormalizeName(adminUserName)
            );

            if (adminUser != null)
            {
                return result;
            }

            adminUser = new IdentityUser(
                GuidGenerator.Create(),
                adminUserName,
                adminEmail,
                tenantId
            )
            {
              //This should be first name and lastname
                Name = adminUserName
                Surname = "surname"
            };

            (await UserManager.CreateAsync(adminUser, adminPassword)).CheckErrors();
            result.CreatedAdminUser = true;

            //"admin" role
            const string adminRoleName = "admin";
            var adminRole = await RoleRepository.FindByNormalizedNameAsync(LookupNormalizer.NormalizeName(adminRoleName));
            if (adminRole == null)
            {
                adminRole = new IdentityRole(
                    GuidGenerator.Create(),
                    adminRoleName,
                    tenantId
                )
                {
                    IsStatic = true,
                    IsPublic = true
                };

                (await RoleManager.CreateAsync(adminRole)).CheckErrors();
                result.CreatedAdminRole = true;
            }

            (await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminUser, adminRoleName)).CheckErrors();

            return result;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the column names of the IdentityUser are still the same:

```
            {
                Name = adminUserName,
                Surname = "surname"
            };
```

Instead of my new column names, so the property names inside ABP `IdentityUser` class are not changed.

[image]

What do I need to do to solve that? Best regards

**--Update--**

I added the property LastName on MigrationService class as:

```
 private async Task SeedDataAsync(Tenant tenant = null)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation($"Executing {(tenant == null ? "host" : tenant.Name + " tenant")} database seed...");
       
  await _dataSeeder.SeedAsync(new DataSeedContext(tenant?.Id)
         .WithProperty(IdentityDataSeedContributor.AdminEmailPropertyName, IdentityDataSeedContributor.AdminEmailDefaultValue)
         .WithProperty(IdentityDataSeedContributor.AdminPasswordPropertyName, IdentityDataSeedContributor.AdminPasswordDefaultValue)
         .WithProperty("LastName", "Test")
        );
        }
```

But still the same error!

Comment: can you provide the DataContext class code ?

Comment: What do you mean by DataContext class, I have no class with that name, did you mean DataSeedContext? @jmvcollaborator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement both DataSeed and the DataSeedContributor. Use the both classes below.

```
[Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
public class CustomIdentityDataSeedContributor : IdentityDataSeedContributor
{
    private IIdentityDataSeeder _identityDataSeeder;

    public CustomIdentityDataSeedContributor(IIdentityDataSeeder identityDataSeeder)
        : base(identityDataSeeder)
    {
        _identityDataSeeder = identityDataSeeder;
    }

    public override Task SeedAsync(DataSeedContext context)
    {
        return _identityDataSeeder.SeedAsync(
           "custom@Custom.com",
           "Pass1234+",
           context?.TenantId
       );

    }
}
```

And

```
[Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
public class CustomIdentityDataSeeder : IdentityDataSeeder
{
    public CustomIdentityDataSeeder(
    IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager,
    IGuidGenerator guidGenerator,
    IIdentityRoleRepository roleRepository,
    IIdentityUserRepository userRepository,
    ILookupNormalizer lookupNormalizer,
    IdentityUserManager userManager,
    IdentityRoleManager roleManager,
    ICurrentTenant currentTenant,
    IOptions<IdentityOptions> identityOptions,
    IdentityUserManager identityUserManager)
    : base(guidGenerator, roleRepository, userRepository, lookupNormalizer, userManager, roleManager, currentTenant, identityOptions)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<IdentityDataSeedResult> SeedAsync(string adminEmail, string adminPassword, Guid? tenantId = null)
    {
        var result = new IdentityDataSeedResult();
        Check.NotNullOrWhiteSpace(adminEmail, nameof(adminEmail));
        Check.NotNullOrWhiteSpace(adminPassword, nameof(adminPassword));
        string adminUserName = "custom";
        if (adminEmail == "admin@abp.io")
        {
            return result;
        }
        if (tenantId != Guid.Empty && tenantId != null)
        {
            adminUserName = "custom2";
            if (adminEmail == "custom@Custom.com")
            {
                adminEmail = "custom2@Custom.com";
            }
        }

        using (CurrentTenant.Change(tenantId))
        {
            //"admin" user

            var adminUser = await UserRepository.FindByNormalizedUserNameAsync(
                LookupNormalizer.NormalizeName(adminUserName)
            );

            if (adminUser != null)
            {
                return result;
            }

            adminUser = new IdentityUser(
                GuidGenerator.Create(),
                adminUserName,
                adminEmail,
                tenantId
            )
            {
                //This should be first name and lastname
                Name = adminUserName,
                Surname = "surname"
            };

            (await UserManager.CreateAsync(adminUser, adminPassword)).CheckErrors();
            result.CreatedAdminUser = true;

            //"admin" role
            const string adminRoleName = "admin";
            var adminRole = await RoleRepository.FindByNormalizedNameAsync(LookupNormalizer.NormalizeName(adminRoleName));
            if (adminRole == null)
            {
                adminRole = new IdentityRole(
                    GuidGenerator.Create(),
                    adminRoleName,
                    tenantId
                )
                {
                    IsStatic = true,
                    IsPublic = true
                };

                (await RoleManager.CreateAsync(adminRole)).CheckErrors();
                result.CreatedAdminRole = true;
            }

            (await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminUser, adminRoleName)).CheckErrors();

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested it and it works.

[image]

Comment: It works!!!!!!!, I don't know if the question is relevant, but how can I update the fields on the edit user form and create a new user for these new ones? it still shows Name and Surname in the UI forms, I thought it is going to be mapped after generate the proxy but it didn't work

Comment: I guess you are want to change the labels, arent you?. You can change the texts for the ui in the language management ui or you override the localization json. You can check the ABP documentstion https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Localization

Comment: Yes, I want to change the labels, the docs explain how to do it with Razor UI, also the fields on edit and user creation are not required... and I set them as required in my db change, I have the Angular UI version, the problem is that I can not access to .html code of that abp views. I think I should create a new question for that

Comment: I created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76239080/rename-abpidentity-columns-on-the-ui-forms) for that.