# Rename AbpIdentity columns on the UI forms?

Tags: c#, .net, abp

I'm working on ABP framework 7.1 with Angular UI.

I already renamed the Name and Surname properties of the abpUsers table and set them as required as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76230228/getting-error-after-update-identity-column-names/76236702?noredirect=1#comment134444692_76236702)

It is running well and smoothly. But now, I want to rename the columns of the UI, Create and Edit user:

Reference image:

[image]

Now, it is showing `Name` and `Surname` instead `First Name` and `Last Name`, these fields have not had the required indicator `*`. And you can also save them without providing value.

I want to do both things:

- Set required properties so the form should throw a required validation if the user try to save them without providing them.
- Rename the fields

I tried to do that with ExtensionConfigurator as:

```
   ObjectExtensionManager.Instance.Modules()
       .ConfigureIdentity(identity =>
       {
           identity.ConfigureUser(user =>
           {
               user.AddOrUpdateProperty<string>(
                   "FirstName",
                   property =>
                   {
                       property.UI.Lookup.DisplayPropertyName = "First Name";
                       property.DisplayName = L("::FirstName");
                   });
   });
       });
```

After adding that code, I ran the proxy generator. But it didn't work; it still showed the `Name` label instead First Name. How should I do that?

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ObjectExtensionManager only works with extra properties. In your case I think you need to customize it with dynamic forms to mark them as required in the UI. Follow the ABP Documentation ->  https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Dynamic-Form-Extensions

You can easy override the labels in the language management UI

[image]

Or you can also override the values in the json. You can follow this blog post in the ABP blogs to do this -> https://community.abp.io/posts/how-to-override-localization-strings-of-depending-modules-ba1oy03l

Here can you find the module localization json for the identity UI -> https://github.com/abpframework/abp/tree/dev/modules/identity/src/Volo.Abp.Identity.Domain.Shared/Volo/Abp/Identity/Localization

Comment: I'm trying to override the localization string, but... how can I know the extension names of Name and Surname properties on the IdentityResource? I tried with     "DisplayName:Abp.Identity.Name": "Custom name" but it didn't work

Comment: You can find this info in the ABP github repos https://github.com/abpframework/abp/tree/dev/modules/identity/src/Volo.Abp.Identity.Domain.Shared/Volo/Abp/Identity/Localization

Comment: It does not have a specific name, but it has this one `"DisplayName:Abp.Identity.User.IsUserNameUpdateEnabled":`, so I think it should be `"DisplayName:Abp.Identity.User.Name":`, but it does not work

Comment: Try "DisplayName:Abp.Identity.UserInfo.Name"

Comment: Got it! I use the Angular chrome extension and I found that name has a display name of:   `displayName: 'AbpIdentity::DisplayName:Name',` we can translate that in the json file to `"DisplayName:Name": "First Name"` and it works!, now you have an idea of how to set the field required? how can I override the UserCreateOrUpdateDto entity?

Comment: `"DisplayName:Abp.Identity.UserInfo.Name"` does not work, but `"DisplayName:Name"` works! Checking how I can set that required, you know how?

Comment: You can try the dynamic forms suggestion in my answer. So far i know is to modify the UI the only way. I only use the razor ui with the abp framework